# where is Where is the TransformationMethod being defined

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am new to Azure b2c IEF policy. Where is the TransformationMethod being defined? Is it defined by Azure? Is there any reference?

TransformationMethod="GenerateJson"

```
  <ClaimsTransformation Id="GenerateEmailRequestBody" TransformationMethod="GenerateJson">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.to.0.email" />
     
    </InputClaims>
```

**Updated**:

Found the reference here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimstransformations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Azure AD B2C, the `TransformationMethod` attribute is predefined by Azure that specifies the **format** in which the claims should be returned.
>
> You can check this **[reference](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/unit-tests/tree/main/claims-transformation)** that contains different types of claim transformation methods along with ***Live Demo*** links.

**"GenerateJson"** method indicates that the input claims should be transformed into JSON format. When I ran the [Live Demo](https://b2clivedemo.b2clogin.com/b2clivedemo.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_CT_GenerateJson/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=cfaf887b-a9db-4b44-ac47-5efff4e2902c&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login) of it, I got below page to input claims:

[image]

After clicking **`Continue`** button, it displayed how the claims will be transformed to **JSON** payload like this:

[image]

This JSON value will be displayed in **Output claims** of B2C ID token like this:

[image]

**Reference:**
[unit-tests/claims-transformation/json at main · azure-ad-b2c/unit-tests · GitHub](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/unit-tests/tree/main/claims-transformation/json#generatejson)